# How to prove $\prod_{k=0}^n\left(2-\frac{2k+1}{n}\right)=-\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n^{n+1}n!}$.

Tags: numerical-methods, products

To finish a proof, I am stuck on the steps of getting from $$\prod_{k=0}^n \left(2-\frac{2k+1}{n}\right)$$ to the form $$-\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n^{n+1} n!}.$$
If it helps, the entire question as follows: we let $n\geq1$ and $x_j$ evenly spaced such that $x_j=(2j-n)/n$ for $j=1,\dots,n.$ Define $\phi_{n+1}(x)=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\dots(x-x_n)$. With this, we want to show that $$\phi_{n+1}(1-1/n)=-\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n^{n+1} n!}.$$

I've written out and manipulated the values to arrive at what I think is the simplest form of the left hand side, as provided above, but I am not sure how to progress from where I'm at.

Comment: Direct calculations give the wanted answer : try rewriting $\left(2-\frac{2k+1}{n}\right)$ as $\left(\frac{2n-(2k+1)}{n}\right)$ and see what you can do afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\prod_{k=0}^n \left(2-\frac{2k+1}{n}\right)
&= \prod_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{2(n-k)-1}{n}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\prod_{k=0}^n (2(n-k)-1) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\prod_{k=0}^n (2k-1) \\
&= -\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1) \\ 
&= -\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1) \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)} \\
&= -\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n} k}{n^{n+1} 2^n \prod_{k=1}^n k} \\
&= -\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n^{n+1}n!}
\end{align}